# Repeating background with an increment

Tags: css, sass, background, linear-gradients

I'm struggling with a bit of CSS, I want a black bar to show every X amount of pixels but I'd want it to increment by about 10px every time it is shown.

E.g first bar appears at 100px, second at 110 and the third at 120.

So far I have used the following background style to achieve the first part (show a bar every X pixels) but it isn't perfect either:

```
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 1405px, black 210px,black 37.4cm)
```

Any css warrior out there that knows of a fix?

**EDIT**

So with a bit of trial and error I have succeeded in placing the line every 1405 pixels with the following code:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 1405px, black 1405px, black 1415px)
```

The problem persists however, the elements are in the place they belong, the line needs to appear after every element (hence the + 10px request).

This is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvEru.jpg
It isn't always 1 element though, there might be more like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npyo1.jpg

The line still has to be placed behind the elements at a set interval (1405 pixels) but it has to increase by 10 every time. (so 1405 pixels, then after 1415 pixels, then after 1425 pixels etc.)

Comment: and between the black, the white should the same length or it need to increment also? maybe you can share a screen of the result?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have attached 2 pictures that showcase the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that with a simple `linear-gradient` we cannot have a non-regular pattern. Here is an idea using some transform and perspective to simualte your pattern where the distance between black line will grow:

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 30px;
  perspective-origin: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grad {
  height: 100vh;
  transform: rotateX(10deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0, #000 10px, #fff 10px, #fff 50px);
  ]
```

```html
<div class="grad">

</div>
```

Or you would need to use multiple gradient and adjust `background-position`. Something you can easily generate with SASS if you want many lines:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 30px;
  perspective-origin: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grad {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(#000,#000),
    linear-gradient(#000,#000),
    linear-gradient(#000,#000),
    linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:100% 10px ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:
    0 0,
    0 50px,
    0 150px,
    0 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grad">

</div>
```

Here a script provided by [@Krypt1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610466/krypt1) to generate the above using SASS:

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/15bd039fdd0803ed79d12762ad6da28f

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you did, and I think I've got it. But this wouldn't work for that 10px increase if the initial value was 1405 would it?

Comment: @RickvanLieshout well it's and idea but not a real solution :) maybe you can tweak the different value to obtain what you want ... I added another solution if you want ;)

Comment: I've implemented a simple mixin in SCSS to generate it automatically based on your answer, take a look: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/15bd039fdd0803ed79d12762ad6da28f

Comment: @Krypt1 yes good one ;) you may added it as answer if you want, or I can added it to mine?

Comment: @RickvanLieshout You may also check the SASS script of Krypt based on my idea

Comment: You can add it to yours, as it's based on your answer ;)

Comment: I will have a look at it tomorrow guys! Thank you both for the work. Cya tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

For stripes to work exactly 10px each, you would need to change the `repeating-linear-gradient` to generate them every 10px from start to end. And then you can use another gradient to hide first 100px with white color, and then change to transparent to show the stripes. 
Here's the snippet:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 100px, transparent 100px, transparent),
              repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 10px, black 10px, black 20px)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This already looks cleaner than my solution, but I can't get the bars to be 29.7cm apart (a4 size).

Also, it doesn't increment so eventually the bars run out of sync. I am having trouble visualising it but if you can get them 29.7 cm apart I can make a picture!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstood the question first. I don't think it's possible to have an incremental size in a single element's gradient. Do you have a full example with HTML? Maybe it would be easier to just change the HTML

Comment: Can't change the html unfortunately, it's generated by a library :)

Comment: Your best bet is to generate the CSS using SCSS then. Take a look at the @TemaniAfif answer, I've added a snippet in SCSS in comments to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which allows you to show background styling from elements behind is to use a pseudoelement positioned behind your div, and make use of `rgba` within your `repeating-lenear-gradient` to have transparent colours.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10px, #000000 10px, #000000 20px);
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: sorry but can you explain the need of the pseudo element when it comes to background?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sure - the basic reason for it is to undo one of the limiting factors of the other answer to this question. The other answer forces this entire div to have a solid background colour as it is using one background to hide another. My solution allows for it to have transparency. For that constraint, the only way I could think of to start the background 100px down the div (as per OP's request) was to actually use a second element.

Comment: sorry but I still don't agree :) you can control the background size and position, here is what you have done with pseudo element : https://jsfiddle.net/mnyh1vfe/

Comment: @TemaniAfif However this now assumes you know the final size of the div beforehand... Then again, you can probably use `calc(100% - 100px)` to get around that limitation... Yes, thank you for sharing that, I'll remember the idea.

Comment: no, am not assuming anything and no need any size of the div ;) I simply did like you ... a gradient that strat from the bottom with a height of 200px, no need to know any div size